# "Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined" error when starting of d3.js force layout graph

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, force-layout

In my project I want to draw a graph using d3.js force layout with following data.

```
Nodes --> [{"name":"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract","type":"s","group":0},
{"name":"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#DatatypeProperty","type":"o","group":1},
{"name":"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageID","type":"s","group":2},
{"name":"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#backwardCompatibleWith","type":"s","group":4},
{"name":"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#OntologyProperty","type":"o","group":5},
{"name":"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/birthDate","type":"s","group":6}, 
{"name":"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/deathDate","type":"s","group":8},
{"name":"http://dbpedia-live.openlinksw.com/sparql","type":"s","group":10},  
{"name":"http://www.w3.org/ns/sparql-service-description#Service","type":"o","group":11},
{"name":"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#incompatibleWith","type":"s","group":12},
{"name":"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#priorVersion","type":"s","group":14},
{"name":"http://dbpedia.org/ontology/wikiPageRevisionID","type":"s","group":16},
{"name":"http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#imports","type":"s","group":18}]

Links --> [{"source":0,"target":1,"uri":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","weight":1,"value":200},
{"source":2,"target":1,"uri":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","weight":1,"value":200},
{"source":4,"target":5,"uri":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","weight":1,"value":200},
{"source":6,"target":1,"uri":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","weight":1,"value":200},
{"source":8,"target":1,"uri":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","weight":1,"value":200},
{"source":10,"target":11,"uri":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","weight":1,"value":200},
{"source":12,"target":5,"uri":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","weight":1,"value":200},
{"source":14,"target":5,"uri":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","weight":1,"value":200},
{"source":16,"target":1,"uri":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","weight":1,"value":200},
{"source":18,"target":5,"uri":"http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type","weight":1,"value":200}]
```

This data has been prepared dynamically in this format.In javascript code when force.start(); function has been called "Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined" error has been throwed. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357974/d3-js-cannot-read-property-weight-of-undefined-when-manually-defining-both-no) related question didn't help to me,so what can I to prevent this error. Also links array is empty or some of links has been removed or when I use "miserables.json" as data javascript which is below works successfully.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var w = 900,
        h = 900;
    var color = d3.scale.category10();

    var nodes = eval('(' + '${graphDrawer.nodes}' + ')');


    var links = eval('(' + '${graphDrawer.links}' + ')');

    var vis = d3.select("#activationGraphDiv").append("svg:svg")
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

        var force = d3.layout.force()
            .gravity(.05)
            .linkDistance(100)
            .charge(-200)
            .size([w, h]);

        var link = vis.selectAll("line.link")
            .data(links)
            .enter().append("svg:line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
            .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
            .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
            .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

        var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .on("mouseover", nodeMouseover)
            .on("mouseout", nodeMouseout);

        node.append("circle")
            .attr("r",10) // Node radius
        .style("fill", "white") // Make the nodes hollow looking
        .style("stroke-width", 4) // Give the node strokes some thickness
        .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.group); } ) // Node stroke colors
        .call(force.drag);

        node.append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "nodetext")
            .attr("dx", 26)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name });

        node.append("title")
            .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

        force.on("tick", function() {
          link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
              .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
              .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
              .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

          node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x+ "," + d.y+ ")"; });
        });

        force
          .nodes(nodes)
          .links(links)
          .start();

        function nodeMouseover() {
            d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
              .duration(250)
              .attr("r",function(d){
                    return 20;
            });
            d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
              .duration(250)
              .style("font", "bold 20px Arial")
              .attr("fill", "Blue");
          }

        function nodeMouseout() {
            d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
               .duration(250)
               .attr("r",function(d){
                    return 10;
            });
            d3.select(this).select("text").transition()
               .duration(250)
               .attr("fill", "Blue")
               .style("font", function(d){
                    return "normal 12px Arial";
               });
          }
    </script>
```

Thanks for any help :D

Comment: I'm not sure, but I thought the `source` and `target` properties in the Links array referred to the index in the Nodes array. With "only" 13 elements in your Nodes array, e.g., the last element in the Links array refers to a non-existent source no. 18. Try removing elements in the Links array with source and target value > 12 and see if that removes your error.