# D3 force layout - linking nodes by name instead of index

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am attempting to link d3 nodes by an ID instead of index (The node ID is generated by my application).

Here are my nodes:

```
"Nodes": [
    {
      "Id": "338",
      "Name": "TEST NODE ONE",
      "Url": "http://www.google.com"
    },
    {
      "Id": "340",
      "Name": "TEST NODE TWO",
      "Url": "http://www.yahoo.com"
    },
    {
      "Id": "341",
      "Name": "TEST NODE THREE",
      "Url": "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    },
    {
      "Id": "342",
      "Name": "TEST NODE FOUR",
      "Url": "http://www.reddit.com"
    }
  ]
```

They are currently linked by index:

```
  "links": [
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 0,
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": 0,
      "target": 1,
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": 1,
      "target": 2,
      "value": "0"
    },
    {
      "source": 3,
      "target": 2,
      "value": "0"
    }
  ]
```

However, I want to link them by "Id":

```
  "Links": [
    {
      "Source": "338",
      "Target": "338",
      "Value": "0"
    },
    {
      "Source": "338",
      "Target": "340",
      "Value": "0"
    },
    {
      "Source": "340",
      "Target": "341",
      "Value": "0"
    },
    {
      "Source": "342",
      "Target": "341",
      "Value": "0"
    }
  ]
```

I've attempted the solution proposed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/d3-js/LWuhBeEipz4/0kZIojCYvhIJ

by adding the following lines before calling force.nodes:

```
  // make links reference nodes directly for this particular data format:
  var hash_lookup = [];
  // make it so we can lookup nodes in O(1):
  json.Nodes.forEach(function(d, i) {
    hash_lookup[d.Id] = d;
  });
  json.Links.forEach(function(d, i) {
    d.source = hash_lookup[d.Source];
    d.target = hash_lookup[d.Target];
  });
```

I've tried debugging the above, but I can't manage to figure it out. I get the following error message (which usually means I haven't set links correctly):

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined`

Link to my full JS: http://jsfiddle.net/9sMrw/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a straightforward way to do this:

```
var edges = [];
json.Links.forEach(function(e) {
    var sourceNode = json.Nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.Id === e.Source;
    })[0],
        targetNode = json.Nodes.filter(function(n) {
            return n.Id === e.Target;
        })[0];

    edges.push({
        source: sourceNode,
        target: targetNode,
        value: e.Value
    });
});

force
    .nodes(json.Nodes)
    .links(edges)
    .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(edges)
    ...
```

Here is a working [PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/20t4F02vsM1U55ktCv66?p=preview). (You should fork it to be safe, in case I inadvertently delete it.)

Comment: What is the reason that `sourceNode` and `targetNode` can be references to objects in the original nodes array? Is it because the DOM elements will eventually reference those exact same objects in the original nodes array? (via `force.nodes(json.Nodes).....start()`)

Comment: Right here, the indeces are translated to nodes: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/force.js?source=cc#L231

So, the code here is skipping that step because the output is what the link object will eventually look like.

Comment: Pretty Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I have applied your changes to my code but the error "Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined" remains... I have no clue...  Please see: https://plnkr.co/edit/OhRrufGi7yF42umrhdBX?p=preview

Comment: Please see these [SO answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357974/d3-js-cannot-read-property-weight-of-undefined-when-manually-defining-both).