# How to create d3.js Collapsible force layout with non tree data?

Tags: d3.js, tree, data-visualization, force-layout, directed-graph

I have a d3 force directed layout with data in a similar structure below. Is it possible to apply collapsible force layout such as http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288 to it? I want a node to be collapsed /expanded on click.

```
{
  "nodes": [
    {"x": 469, "y": 410},
    {"x": 493, "y": 364},
    {"x": 442, "y": 365},
    {"x": 467, "y": 314},
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source":  0, "target":  1},
    {"source":  1, "target":  2},
    {"source":  2, "target":  0},
    {"source":  1, "target":  3},
    {"source":  3, "target":  2},
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, perhaps this is what you are looking for. I edited the demo you linked to. Now when a source node is collapsed, we iterate over all edges and look for other nodes it has edges to.

for each target node that the source node has an edge to, we increment it's collapsing count. If a node has a collapsing count of greater than zero, it is not displayed.

When we uncollapse a node, we do the same thing, except we decrement from the collapsing count.

We need this collapsing count, since, as we are not in a tree, nodes can have more than one node which should cause them to collapse.

I made this work for directed graphs, though I'm not sure that's what you wanted.

Let me know what you think!

The json I used:

```
  {
    "nodes": [
     {"x": 469, "y": 410},
     {"x": 493, "y": 364},
     {"x": 442, "y": 365},
     {"x": 467, "y": 314}
 ],
     "links": [
      {"source":  0, "target":  1},
      {"source":  1, "target":  2},
      {"source":  2, "target":  0},
      {"source":  1, "target":  3},
      {"source":  3, "target":  2}
  ]
 }
```

Modified tutorial code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Force-Directed Graph</title>
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  stroke: #3182bd;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #9ecae1;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500,
    root;

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([width, height])
    .on("tick", tick);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

//Added markers to indicate that this is a directed graph
svg.append("defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["arrow"])
    .enter().append("marker")
    .attr("id", function(d) { return d; })
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 4)
    .attr("markerHeight", 4)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");

var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.selectAll(".node");

d3.json("graph.json", function(json) {
  root = json;
  //Give nodes ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = root.nodes[i];
    node.id = i;
    node.collapsing = 0;
    node.collapsed = false;
  }
  //Give links ids and initialize variables
  for(var i=0; i<root.links.length; i++) {
    var link = root.links[i];
    link.source = root.nodes[link.source];
    link.target = root.nodes[link.target];
    link.id = i;
  }

  update();
});

function update() {
  //Keep only the visible nodes
  var nodes = root.nodes.filter(function(d) {
    return d.collapsing == 0;
  });
  var links = root.links;
  //Keep only the visible links
  links = root.links.filter(function(d) {
    return d.source.collapsing == 0 && d.target.collapsing == 0;
  });

  force
      .nodes(nodes)
      .links(links)
      .start();

  // Update the links…
  link = link.data(links, function(d) { return d.id; });

  // Exit any old links.
  link.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new links.
  link.enter().insert("line", ".node")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
      .attr("marker-end", "url(#arrow)");

  // Update the nodes…
  node = node.data(nodes, function(d){ return d.id; }).style("fill", color);

  // Exit any old nodes.
  node.exit().remove();

  // Enter any new nodes.
  node.enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
      .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
      .style("fill", color)
      .on("click", click)
      .call(force.drag);
}

function tick() {
  link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

  node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
}

// Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
function color(d) {
  return d.collapsed ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (!d3.event.defaultPrevented) {
    //check if link is from this node, and if so, collapse
    root.links.forEach(function(l) {
      if(l.source.id == d.id) {
        if(d.collapsed){
          l.target.collapsing--;
        } else {
          l.target.collapsing++;
        }
      }
    });
    d.collapsed = !d.collapsed;
  }
  update();
}

</script>
```

Comment: thank you for the code. It works as expected. Additional requirements here, I need to link the nodes by nodes' ID instead of index following this example [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986466/d3-force-layout-linking-nodes-by-na‌​‌​me-instead-of-index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986466/d3-force-layout-linking-nodes-by-na‌​‌​me-instead-of-index). Besides, I want to make them bounded to the svg box and add text to the nodes. How should I modify the code?

Comment: @CY- did you ever find an answer for this?

Comment: Does anyone know how to do it for d3.js v4?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var width = 960,height = 500;

    var force = d3.layout.force().size([width, height]).charge(-400)
                .linkDistance(40)
                .on("tick", tick);

         var drag = force.drag().on("dragstart", dragstart);

           var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", width)
                        .attr("height", height);

           var link = svg.selectAll(".link"),
                  node = svg.selectAll(".node");

            d3.json("graph.json", function(error, graph) {
                     force.nodes(graph.nodes).links(graph.links)
                         .start();

        link = link.data(graph.links).enter().append("line")
                      .attr("class", "link");

                  node = node.data(graph.nodes)
                 .enter().append("circle")
                 .attr("class", "node")
                 .attr("r", 12)
                 .call(drag);
         });

         function tick() {
              link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
              .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
              .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
              .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

             node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
                  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
           }



           function dragstart(d) {
                  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);
              }
```

You should use json file like this:

graph.json

```
      {
        "nodes": [
         {"x": 469, "y": 410},
         {"x": 493, "y": 364},
         {"x": 442, "y": 365},
         {"x": 467, "y": 314},
     ],
         "links": [
          {"source":  0, "target":  1},
          {"source":  1, "target":  2},
          {"source":  2, "target":  0},
          {"source":  1, "target":  3},
          {"source":  3, "target":  2},
      ]
     }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm looking for collapsible and expandable nodes on click.

Comment: More like [http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1062288), but my json is defined differently.