# Why is my d3 map function returning an undefined source attribute?

Tags: javascript, csv, dictionary, d3.js

I'm new with d3js and I'm having some issues trying to map a csv file to the links of the force layout.

this is my csv file:

```
node,edges,centrality_degree
1,"[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5)]",1.0
2,"[(2, 1), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5)]",1.0
3,"[(3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5)]",1.0
4,"[(4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 5)]",1.0
5,"[(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4)]",1.0
```

I want to set the edges values to the links attribute of the d3.layout.force(), however when mapping the values, I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined

I don't know also if is it correct to return an array with a bunch of objects, that's what I'm getting on the console. 5 arrays with 4 objects each, each object with its source and target attribute. The attributes are all correct, except for the 5 array. I am getting an undefined value for the first source value of it. It was supposed to be 5.

Here is my code:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
    .size([w, h]);

d3.csv("{{ g }}", function(d) {

    var nodes = d3.values(d.map( function(d){ return +d.node; } ));

    var links_list = d.map( function(d) {

        list_array = JSON.parse(d.edges.replace(/\(/g,"[").replace(/\)/g,"]"));

        var i, len = list_array.length;

        links = [];

        for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
            links.push({source: list_array[i][0] ,target: list_array[i][1] });
        }

        console.log(links);

        #console result:
        #[Object, Object, Object, Object]
        #[Object, Object, Object, Object]
        #[Object, Object, Object, Object]
        #[Object, Object, Object, Object]
        #expanding one array:
            #0: Object
            #1: Object
            #2: Object
            #3: Object
        #[Object, Object, Object, Object]
            #expanding the array[5][0] object: 
            #0: Object
                #source: undefined
                #target: 2
                #__proto__: Object

    });

    force
        .nodes(nodes)
        .links(links)
        .start();

...

});
```

What am I doing wrong and why I'm getting this error?

I appreciate your help.

Comment: The numbers you specify as source and target for the links should be indices into the array of nodes, not node IDs. They start from 0, not from 1. If you want to use the IDs, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986466/d3-force-layout-linking-nodes-by-name-instead-of-index

Comment: @LarsKotthoff, they're indices to the array. The number 0 is a reference for the first item of the array on the console.

Comment: The numbers in your data aren't -- they start at 1 and go up to 5 for 5 nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The values of the source and target attributes should be specified as
>   indexes into the nodes array; these will be replaced by references
>   after the call to force start.

Note that array indices start from 0 and not from 1. But in your data from csv, you have links like `(5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4)` and your nodes array has 5 elements only; index of last element would be 4. You should have reduced these numbers to 1 to represent the actual nodes.

**For example:**

```
var nodes = [{ name: "A", id: 1},{ name: "B", id: 2}];
```

Force layout expects the link array as shown below.

```
var links = [{ source:0, target: 1 }];
```

Hope you got the problem. You will have to do as shown below to get the actual indices.

```
 for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
    links.push({source: list_array[i][0]-1 ,target: list_array[i][1]-1 });
 }
```