# D3js Force Layout - Alternative to using indexes for source and target

Tags: d3.js

```
{

"nodes":[{"name":"1","group":5},{"name":"2","group":5},{"name":"3","group":5},{"name":"4","group":0}],

"links":[{"source":1,"target":2,"event_time":1}]

}
```

So I have this JSON object where I would like to delete the nodes which have no links. For this I'd have to remove the nodes from the "nodes" array and then adjust all indexes in "links", this seems computationally arduous.

[mbostock example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1095795) <- This is an example to use js objects instead of indexes. I therefore tried using

```
{

"nodes":[{"name":"1","group":5},{"name":"2","group":5},{"name":"3","group":5},{"name":"4","group":0}],

"links":[{"source":{"name":"2","group":5},"target":{"name":"3","group":5},"event_time":1}]

}
```

but that didn't work either. I'm using a large json file so it wouldn't be optimal to instantiate objects as I go along. 
Is there a way to do this?

I'm new to js and D3js.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986466/d3-force-layout-linking-nodes-by-name-instead-of-index)?

Comment: Kinda, but not really. I know how to look up sources from nodes. The problem is when I delete nodes and links, I have to calculate indexes of sources and links all over again. I want to know if there's a better way to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. If you delete things, you'll have to update stuff.

Comment: Well, you could just mark the orphan nodes with a property instead of deleting them from the `nodes` array. Then use that property to determine whether or not to add the node to the DOM. That won't help with the force layout computation, but it would still reduce the performance impact on the browser. And, of course, the orphaned nodes wouldn't appear on the page. Not sure if that's enough for your problem.