# D3 force layout - changing link array source and target to node id based on string comparison

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, directed-graph

I am trying to create an array of links that conforms to the expected pattern of a link when used with d3 force layout graph e.g:

```
("id": someId, "source": 2, "target": 3)
```

My current link array has a different format and I need to transform it to the correct format, which is the index of the nodes as source and target.

I tried to loop over the links array, and then for each invididual link, loop over the nodes array and then match the nodes labels with the link source and target (a string comparison) and then override/save/assign the id to the link source / target.

```
   /*Example of nodes[]
    { "id": 1, "label": "Address"},
    { "id": 3, "label": "City"),
    { "id": 4, "label": "Country"}

    Example of wrongly formatted links[]
    { "id": "AddressCity", "source": "City", "target": "Address"},
    { "id": "CityCountry", "source": "Address", "target": "City"}*/

    // Try 1 - the graph explodes and unendless errors appear...
    for (var i=0; i < links.length; i++){
        for (var j=0; j <nodes.length; j++){
            if (nodes[j].label === links[i].source){
                links[i].source = nodes[j].id;
            }
            else if (nodes[j].label === links[i].target){
                links[i].target = nodes[j].id;
            }
        }
    }        

    // Try 2 - seems to do the same as try 1: the graph explodes 
    links.forEach(function(l){
        nodes.forEach(function(n){
            // City === City
            if (n.label === l.source){
                // assign to the source of link AddressCity: the id 3
                l.source = n.id
            }
            if (n.label === l.target){
                l.target = n.id
            }
        });
    });

    // Try 3 - syntax error?
    links.forEach(function(l){
        var sourceLink = nodes.forEach(function(n){
            if (n.label === l.source){
                return l.source = n.id;
            }})[0],
            targetLink = nodes.forEach(function(n){
            if (n.label === l.target){
                return l.target = n.id;
            }})[0];

        links.push({
            source: l.source,
            target: l.target
        });
    });
```

Try 3 is based on [D3 force layout - linking nodes by name instead of index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986466/d3-force-layout-linking-nodes-by-name-instead-of-index) only then in reverse logic, or at least an attempt. Try 3 gives `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` error.

**How can I correctly build up the desired link array?**

Full code to see the graph fleeing from the screen (feature not bug ;) ): http://plnkr.co/edit/Bx0qe8DNEsnFgLhkxbfS

Comment: Can you provide a plunker which uses the code you have written here?
EDIT: I was searching for the wrong thing.. I've found you've shared an implementation with the second `try`.. right?

Comment: Adjusted the plunker example. See lines 206 to 258 for the snippet above. Try 1 is uncommented.

Comment: Reading the logs you printed it looks like you've got plenty of nodes with `NaN` coordinates. This leads to errors when you `call` the `positionNode` function and set the `x1`,`x2`,`y1`,`y2` `attr`s

Comment: Thanks for your comment @FredMaggiowski. You probably mean the `positionEdge` function is called? I understand that the current link array is causing the positionEdge function to throw all the errors, but how do I fix the link array in such a way that it doesnt anymore?

Comment: Could it be that the `positionEdge` function accepts two parameters `edge` and `nodes` but you're only passing one via the `.call( )` d3 function?

Comment: I think that is intended. Even if I change line 268 to `.call(positionEdge, links, nodes)` the graph still explodes. Here is the example I am using tas reference (hard coded data and very much WIP) http://plnkr.co/edit/hhT1RpEr4xmXhnUSM6ei?p=preview