# How to connect edges with nodes based on nodes id in d3.js graph library

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

This code is working fine with the below given JSON data1 object but i want this code to work with this new_json Object. I want Links to be made on the nodes id.Any help ?

```
 var new_json = {{"nodes": [{ "id": 124587, "name": "paper1", "citation": 5, "group": 1 },
{ "id": 178456, "name": "paper2", "citation": 8, "group": 2 }],
"links": [{ "source": 124587, "target": 178456, "name": "A-B-1", "value": 8 }]};

function load_graph(text) {
            var color = d3.scale.category20();           
            var data1 = {
                "nodes": [
                    { "id": 0, "name": "paper1", "citation": 5, "group": 1 },
                    { "id": 1, "name": "paper2", "citation": 8, "group": 2 },
                    { "id": 2, "name": "paper3", "citation": 12, "group": 3 },
                    { "id": 3, "name": "paper4", "citation": 25, "group": 4 },
                    { "id": 4, "name": "paper5", "citation": 15, "group": 5 },
                    { "id": 5, "name": "paper6", "citation": 5, "group": 1 },
                    { "id": 6, "name": "paper7", "citation": 8, "group": 2 },
                    { "id": 7, "name": "paper8", "citation": 12, "group": 3 },
                    { "id": 8, "name": "paper9", "citation": 25, "group": 4 },
                    { "id": 9, "name": "paper10", "citation": 15, "group": 5 }
                ],
                "links": [
                    { "source": 0, "target": 1, "name": "A-B-1", "value": 8 },
                    { "source": 0, "target": 1, "name": "A-B-2", "value": 24 },
                    { "source": 0, "target": 2, "name": "A-C-1", "value": 12 },
                    { "source": 0, "target": 2, "name": "A-C-3", "value": 44 },
                    { "source": 2, "target": 3, "name": "A-D-1", "value": 11 },
                    { "source": 2, "target": 3, "name": "A-D-2", "value": 35 },
                    { "source": 2, "target": 4, "name": "A-E-1", "value": 16 },
                    { "source": 2, "target": 4, "name": "A-E-5", "value": 30 },
                    { "source": 4, "target": 5, "name": "A-B-1", "value": 8 },
                    { "source": 4, "target": 5, "name": "A-B-2", "value": 24 },
                    { "source": 5, "target": 6, "name": "A-C-1", "value": 12 },
                    { "source": 5, "target": 6, "name": "A-C-3", "value": 44 },
                    { "source": 5, "target": 7, "name": "A-D-1", "value": 11 },
                    { "source": 5, "target": 7, "name": "A-D-2", "value": 35 },
                    { "source": 7, "target": 8, "name": "A-E-1", "value": 16 },
                    { "source": 7, "target": 8, "name": "A-E-5", "value": 30 },
                    { "source": 8, "target": 3, "name": "A-C-1", "value": 12 },
                    { "source": 8, "target": 3, "name": "A-C-3", "value": 44 },
                    { "source": 8, "target": 9, "name": "A-D-1", "value": 11 },
                    { "source": 8, "target": 9, "name": "A-D-2", "value": 35 }
                ]
            };

            // used to store the number of links between two nodes. 
            // mLinkNum[data.links[i].source + "," + data.links[i].target] = data.links[i].linkindex;
            var mLinkNum = {};

            // sort links first
            sortLinks();

            // set up linkIndex and linkNumer, because it may possible multiple links share the same source and target node
            setLinkIndexAndNum();

            var w = 960,
                h = 500;

            var force = d3.layout.force()
                          .nodes(d3.values(data1.nodes))
                          .links(data1.links)
                          .size([w, h])
                          .linkDistance(200)
                          .charge(-300)
                          .on("tick", tick)
                          .start();

            var svg = d3.select(".graphContainer").append("svg:svg")
                        .attr("width", w)
                        .attr("height", h);

            var path = svg.append("svg:g")
                          .selectAll("line")
                          .data(force.links())
                          .enter().append("svg:path")
                          .attr("class", "link")
                          .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });


            var circle = svg.append("svg:g")
                            .selectAll("circle")
                            .data(force.nodes())
                            .enter().append("svg:circle")
                            .attr("r", function (d) { return (d.citation); })
                            .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); })
                            .call(force.drag);

            var text = svg.append("svg:g")
                          .selectAll("g")
                          .data(force.nodes())
                          .enter().append("svg:g");

            // A copy of the text with a thick white stroke for legibility.
            text.append("svg:text")
                .attr("x", 8)
                .attr("y", ".31em")
                .attr("class", "shadow")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

            text.append("svg:text")
                .attr("x", 8)
                .attr("y", ".31em")
                .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

            // Use elliptical arc path segments to doubly-encode directionality.
            function tick() {
                path.attr("d", function (d) {
                    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                    // get the total link numbers between source and target node
                    var lTotalLinkNum = mLinkNum[d.source.id + "," + d.target.id] || mLinkNum[d.target.id + "," + d.source.id];
                    if (lTotalLinkNum > 1) {
                        // if there are multiple links between these two nodes, we need generate different dr for each path
                        dr = dr / (1 + (1 / lTotalLinkNum) * (d.linkindex - 1));
                    }
                    // generate svg path
                    return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y +
                        "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 1," + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y +
                        "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0 0," + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y;
                });

                // Add tooltip to the connection path
                path.append("svg:title")
                    .text(function (d, i) { return d.name; });

                circle.attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });

                text.attr("transform", function (d) {
                    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
                });
            }

            // sort the links by source, then target
            function sortLinks() {
                data.links.sort(function (a, b) {
                    if (a.source > b.source) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else if (a.source < b.source) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    else {
                        if (a.target > b.target) {
                            return 1;
                        }
                        if (a.target < b.target) {
                            return -1;
                        }
                        else {
                            return 0;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            //any links with duplicate source and target get an incremented 'linknum'
            function setLinkIndexAndNum() {
                for (var i = 0; i < data.links.length; i++) {
                    if (i != 0 &&
                        data.links[i].source == data.links[i - 1].source &&
                        data.links[i].target == data.links[i - 1].target) {
                        data.links[i].linkindex = data.links[i - 1].linkindex + 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        data.links[i].linkindex = 1;
                    }
                    // save the total number of links between two nodes
                    if (mLinkNum[data.links[i].target + "," + data.links[i].source] !== undefined) {
                        mLinkNum[data.links[i].target + "," + data.links[i].source] = data.links[i].linkindex;
                    }
                    else {
                        mLinkNum[data.links[i].source + "," + data.links[i].target] = data.links[i].linkindex;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 force layout - linking nodes by name instead of index](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986466/d3-force-layout-linking-nodes-by-name-instead-of-index)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically force layout works off index's rather than id's or names. So you have to specifically say you want to link via id in your case :

```
var edges = [];
data.links.forEach(function(e) {
    var sourceNode = data.nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.id === e.source;
    })[0],
        targetNode = data.nodes.filter(function(n) {
            return n.id === e.target;
        })[0];

    edges.push({
        source: sourceNode,
        target: targetNode
    });
});
```

The code above checks which node has the same id as the links Source then pushes that into the source of the edges array and the same for the target. Then use this edges array to create the graph :

Force :

```
force
      .nodes(data.nodes)
      .links(edges)
```

And for the links  :

```
var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
          .data(edges)
```

Here is a fiddle I have implemented with your `new_json` : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/60oLwg8t/1/

Or here :

```js
 
  var data = 
      {
        "nodes": [{
          "id": 124587,
          "name": "paper1",
          "citation": 5,
          "group": 1
        }, {
          "id": 178456,
          "name": "paper2",
          "citation": 8,
          "group": 2
        }],
        "links": [{
          "source": 124587,
          "target": 178456,
          "name": "A-B-1",
          "value": 8
        }]
      };

console.log(data.nodes)
console.log(data.links)
      var width = 960,
        height = 500;

      var color = d3.scale.category20();

      var force = d3.layout.force()
        .charge(-120)
        .linkDistance(30)
        .size([width, height]);

      var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

      var edges = [];
data.links.forEach(function(e) {
    var sourceNode = data.nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.id === e.source;
    })[0],
        targetNode = data.nodes.filter(function(n) {
            return n.id === e.target;
        })[0];

    edges.push({
        source: sourceNode,
        target: targetNode,
        value: e.Value
    });
});


        force
          .nodes(data.nodes)
          .links(edges)
          .start();
        var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
          .data(edges)
          .enter().append("line")
          .attr("class", "link")
          .style("stroke-width", 2);

        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
          .data(data.nodes)
          .enter().append("circle")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("r", 5)
          .style("fill", 'red')
          .call(force.drag);

        node.append("title")
          .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
          });

        force.on("tick", function() {
          link.attr("x1", function(d) {
              return d.source.x;
            })
            .attr("y1", function(d) {
              return d.source.y;
            })
            .attr("x2", function(d) {
              return d.target.x;
            })
            .attr("y2", function(d) {
              return d.target.y;
            });

          node.attr("cx", function(d) {
              return d.x;
            })
            .attr("cy", function(d) {
              return d.y;
            });
        });
```

```css
.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your time, means alot to me :).Your code is working fine but i want to have two edges between every pair of nodes sow hen i do this "links": [{
              "source": 124587,
              "target": 178456,
              "name": "A-B-1",
              "value": 8
          }, {
              "source": 124587,
              "target": 178456,
              "name": "A-B-2",
              "value": 8
          }] i only see nodes no edges.

Comment: I have changed my code according to yours but when i add two links having same source and destination i cant see even a single link.

Comment: when i add single link between pair of nodes it works fine. but i want two links between every pair of nodes.

Comment: @HamdanSultan https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/wmkue6ea/3/. You weren't bringing d.linkindex through in the edges array. Line 118. And the tick function was wrong. Check update

Comment: As i am working on edges width too, i want to set thickness of edge according to the value in link but your updated code is only increasing the width of last link i added.

Comment: @HamdanSultan just read the code. I made changes to the width for testing reasons. Here is it resolved : https://jsfiddle.net/thatOneGuy/wmkue6ea/5/

Comment: Thanks alot bro :)