# How to add text to d3.js nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, text, nodes

Making first steps with d3.js I have taken sample code from [this sample page](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) and try to change it the way I need it.

Actually I want to add TEXT to the colored nodes. They already have a title property set, but I can't manage to add not-tooltip text.

Reference and introduction documents did not help on this.

Here is the code, my fortuneless approach is marked:

```
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

    //d3.select("body").transition()
    //.style("background-color", "black");

d3.json("miserables1.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
      .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });     

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      //.attr("r", 20)
      .attr("r",  function(d) { return d.radius; }) 
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

// -----> my approach to add text to the nodes:
  node.insert("div", ":first-child")
     .append("text")
     .style("fill", "#0000ff")
     .attr("width", "10")
     .attr("height", "10")
     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
// -----> end of fortuneless approach.

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Why are you using the selector 'first-child' and 'node.insert'? As per my understanding, you are trying to add text to all the nodes? I guess you should just add '.text' where you define style etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the nodes:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
.enter().append("circle")
```

And look at what you did after that:

```
node.insert("div", ":first-child")
 .append("text")
```

You'll see the problem: You are trying to append texts to circles, and this doesn't work. Besides that, you *can not*  append `<div>` or any other HTML tag to a SVG (`foreignObject` is a different story).

So, this is a solution:

```
var myText = svg.selectAll(".mytext")
                .data(graph.nodes)
                .enter()
                .append("text")
                //the rest of your code
```

Here is the working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/UwQfPscQiOg87IEMYtET?p=preview

Comment: I added your code but no change, it seems not to work.

Comment: Try to make a working fiddle or Plunker, and I'll give a  look.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/HAjzIqyzzIr1JuipFpdx I am unsure this is configured correctly becuase nothing happens pressung PLAY, but however the code is there.

Comment: Excellent. I'm on my mobile now, but I'll check it in a couple of hours. The most important is having "lesmiserables.json" there.

Comment: The json file is added to the "repo". I am actually looking at another challenge: AFAIKS the connections are created bewtween the "source" and "target" nodes by adressing the ongoing index of the nodes. If you could also look at an oppertunity to address the nodes by a reference (id, name) instead of the index this would be perfect.

Comment: Here is your plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/UwQfPscQiOg87IEMYtET?p=preview

Comment: regarding your last question, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986466/d3-force-layout-linking-nodes-by-name-instead-of-index

Comment: Fantastic, I forgot   myText.attr("x", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("y", function(d) { return d.y; }); first, now its working! TY

Comment: One last thing: you cannot drag anything with that amount of texts! Do `"pointer-events", "none"`, like I did here: https://plnkr.co/edit/HzvbFtWmuJZECyHsJWao?p=preview