# "target is undefined" in d3.force implementation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, undefined, force-layout

I am new to coding and recently began testing d3 to generate a force directed graph where nodes are linked by IDs instead of index.

I successfully implemented [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986466/d3-force-layout-linking-nodes-by-name-instead-of-index). However, this works only when my link array includes defined source or target IDs. When undefined IDs are included (the JSON data I am using inevitably contains a certain amount of them), I get this error :

```
TypeError: o.target is undefined
```

I reproduced the error in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e266vgq9/1/).

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Davide

Comment: A link does only make sense in the context of two nodes; it's the logical connection between them. If you have dangling links with one end refering to a none existing node, this will break the force layout. You have to either get rid of these links or attach a dummy node to it in case you want to keep the link.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Because of the very nature of the data, I cannot get rid of the links referring to undefined nodes. Would it be possible to simply tell the script to ignore them?

Comment: Ok, let me start the other way round: What would you need those links for? Would you like to visualize them? What do you expect them to look like? If there is no node on one end, there is no way to tell where that end will be placed on the graphic. It will also be ignored by the force's calculations, which will render it static. If you won't display it, you can, of  course, filter your links' array for non-existing nodes, which is what I mean by getting rid of those links.

Comment: I would like to "hide" (to filter as you said) links' array for non-existing nodes. How do you suggest to do that?

Comment: Just put a `if (sourceNode && targetNode)` before doing `edges.push()` like here: https://jsfiddle.net/e266vgq9/2/. If either node is undefined the link will thus not be added.

Comment: Thank you very much: it works like a charm