# Force Directed D3 Graph -- Debug

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

To my complete and utter joy, I discovered this amazing [article](http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/) that gave me a walk-through of how to create a nice D3 force layout graph.

However, I'm struggling on the JSON source: 
The author's JSON "links" attribute doesn't make as much sense to me (seen in my JSFiddle). I would like to use the JSON as seen below. When I attempted to change it to the below JSON source, I got a "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" error in the console.

My JSFiddle can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/KateJean/2sf9ot84/) and below is the original JSON source I am attempting to use:

```
   {
  "nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Napoleon", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mlle.Baptistine", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Mme.Magloire", "group": 1},
    {"id": "CountessdeLo", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Geborand", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Champtercier", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Cravatte", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Count", "group": 1},
    {"id": "OldMan", "group": 1},
    {"id": "Labarre", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Valjean", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Marguerite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.deR", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Isabeau", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Gervais", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Tholomyes", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Listolier", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fameuil", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Blacheville", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Favourite", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Dahlia", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Zephine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Fantine", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Mme.Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Thenardier", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Cosette", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Javert", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Fauchelevent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Bamatabois", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Perpetue", "group": 3},
    {"id": "Simplice", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Scaufflaire", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Woman1", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Judge", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Champmathieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Brevet", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Chenildieu", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Cochepaille", "group": 2},
    {"id": "Pontmercy", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Boulatruelle", "group": 6},
    {"id": "Eponine", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Anzelma", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Woman2", "group": 5},
    {"id": "MotherInnocent", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Gribier", "group": 0},
    {"id": "Jondrette", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Mme.Burgon", "group": 7},
    {"id": "Gavroche", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Magnon", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mme.Pontmercy", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mlle.Vaubois", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Lt.Gillenormand", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Marius", "group": 8},
    {"id": "BaronessT", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Mabeuf", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Enjolras", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Combeferre", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Prouvaire", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Feuilly", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Courfeyrac", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Bahorel", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Bossuet", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Joly", "group": 8},
    {"id": "Grantaire", "group": 8},
    {"id": "MotherPlutarch", "group": 9},
    {"id": "Gueulemer", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Babet", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Claquesous", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Montparnasse", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Toussaint", "group": 5},
    {"id": "Child1", "group": 10},
    {"id": "Child2", "group": 10},
    {"id": "Brujon", "group": 4},
    {"id": "Mme.Hucheloup", "group": 8}
  ],
  "links": [
    {"source": "Napoleon", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Baptistine", "target": "Myriel", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Myriel", "value": 10},
    {"source": "Mme.Magloire", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 6},
    {"source": "CountessdeLo", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Geborand", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Champtercier", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cravatte", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Count", "target": "Myriel", "value": 2},
    {"source": "OldMan", "target": "Myriel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Labarre", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mme.Magloire", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Mlle.Baptistine", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Valjean", "target": "Myriel", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Marguerite", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.deR", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Isabeau", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gervais", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Listolier", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fameuil", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Listolier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Blacheville", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Favourite", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Dahlia", "target": "Favourite", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Zephine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Listolier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Fameuil", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Blacheville", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Favourite", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Dahlia", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Zephine", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Marguerite", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Fantine", "target": "Valjean", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 13},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Thenardier", "target": "Valjean", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Valjean", "value": 31},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cosette", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Valjean", "value": 17},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Fantine", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Javert", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 8},
    {"source": "Fauchelevent", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bamatabois", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Perpetue", "target": "Fantine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Perpetue", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Fantine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Simplice", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Scaufflaire", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Woman1", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Judge", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Champmathieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Brevet", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Chenildieu", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Judge", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Champmathieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Brevet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Chenildieu", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Cochepaille", "target": "Bamatabois", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Pontmercy", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Boulatruelle", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Eponine", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Eponine", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Anzelma", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Valjean", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Woman2", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 3},
    {"source": "MotherInnocent", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gribier", "target": "Fauchelevent", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Burgon", "target": "Jondrette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Mme.Burgon", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gavroche", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Magnon", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "target": "Valjean", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Pontmercy", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mlle.Vaubois", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Lt.Gillenormand", "target": "Cosette", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Mlle.Gillenormand", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Pontmercy", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Lt.Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Cosette", "value": 21},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Valjean", "value": 19},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Tholomyes", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Eponine", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Marius", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 4},
    {"source": "BaronessT", "target": "Gillenormand", "value": 1},
    {"source": "BaronessT", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mabeuf", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Marius", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Javert", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Enjolras", "target": "Valjean", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 15},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Marius", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Combeferre", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Prouvaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Feuilly", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Marius", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 17},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 13},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Courfeyrac", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Bahorel", "target": "Marius", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Marius", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 12},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 10},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 9},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Bossuet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 7},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Joly", "target": "Marius", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Combeferre", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Joly", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Feuilly", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Grantaire", "target": "Prouvaire", "value": 1},
    {"source": "MotherPlutarch", "target": "Mabeuf", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 5},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Gueulemer", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 6},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Javert", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Babet", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Babet", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 4},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Mme.Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Claquesous", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Babet", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Montparnasse", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Cosette", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Javert", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Toussaint", "target": "Valjean", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Child1", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Child2", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 2},
    {"source": "Child2", "target": "Child1", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Babet", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Gueulemer", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Thenardier", "value": 3},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Eponine", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Claquesous", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Brujon", "target": "Montparnasse", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bossuet", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Joly", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Grantaire", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Bahorel", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Courfeyrac", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Gavroche", "value": 1},
    {"source": "Mme.Hucheloup", "target": "Enjolras", "value": 1}
  ]
}
```

It should be noted that the JSON seen above and the article where I found my examples are based on the same source: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

Comment: What version of D3 are you using?

Comment: V3. Original example is V4. Unfortunately, I'm constrained to V3 in my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a different version of D3 in your JSFiddle. Bostock's example uses v4. So, in your `links` array each `object` needs the `source` and `target` to be the *index* of the respective nodes.

For example, if you're creating a link between `"Myriel"` and `"Napolean"`, then the link object would look like `{"source": 0, "target": 1, value: 3}`.

The chosen answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23986466/d3-force-layout-linking-nodes-by-name-instead-of-index) shows a straight forward way to convert the links.

But, for your convenience here's the code:

```js
var links = [];

json.links.forEach(function(e) {
  var sourceNode = json.Nodes.filter(function(n) {
    return n.id === e.source;
  })[0];
  
  var targetNode = json.Nodes.filter(function(n) {
    return n.id === e.target;
  })[0];

  links.push({
    source: sourceNode,
    target: targetNode,
    value: e.value
  });
});
```