# D3 Force Directed Graph Redraw with Less Edges

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, graph

I am trying to add a threshold to a force directed graph, where I will only include edges between vertices that that are above some threshold I store in a map. My slider is partly working, and the edges successfully get removed. 
[image: Before...]

[image: After...]

However, after the edges are removed, the graph stops animating, and there is an error in the console when calling force.start(). Do I really need to add unique ids? In the JSFiddle I linked, he does not do that, and his slider works with no problems.

Thanks!
[image: Console Error]
There are multiple answers on StackOverflow to similar questions, and I have used them to fix my obvious errors (such as [d3.js: "Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined" when manually defining both nodes and links for force layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357974/d3-js-cannot-read-property-weight-of-undefined-when-manually-defining-both)), but I am down to this one. I am using this example: http://jsfiddle.net/simonraper/TdHgx/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=TdHgx from this website: http://www.coppelia.io/2014/07/an-a-to-z-of-extra-features-for-the-d3-force-layout/

I will send the relevant JS.

```
         function draw(occurence) {
        var ratio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;

        var width = Math.min(700,0.8*$(window).width()), height = 700;
        var color = d3.scale.category20();
        var svg = d3.select("#" + occurence).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height)
            .attr("id", "#" + occurence + "svg");

        d3.json(occurence + ".json", function(error, graph) {
          if (error) throw error;

          var force = d3.layout.force()
            .charge(-120)
            .linkDistance(50)
            .size([width, height]);

          force
              .nodes(graph.nodes)
              .links(graph.links)
              .start();
          if (occurence == "occurrences3") {
            console.log(graph.nodes);
            console.log(graph.links);
          }

          var graphRec=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(graph)); //Add this line

          var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
              .data(graph.links)
            .enter().append("line")
              .attr("class", "link")
              .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

          var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(graph.nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("r", 5)
              .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
              .call(force.drag);

          node.append("title")
              .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

          force.on("tick", function() {
            link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

          node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
              .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
          });

          node.on("dblclick", function(d) {
            $("#uncuratedGraphsModal").modal();
            var d = d3.select(this).node().__data__;
            var name = d.name;
            $("#uncuratedGraphsModalHeader").text("Node " + name);
            $("#uncuratedGraphsModalBody").empty();
            var edge_by_person = edge_by_person_per_threshold[occurence + "edge_by_person"];
            var edges = edge_by_person[name];
            edges.sort(function(a,b) {
                return a.dest - b.dest;
            });
            $.each(edges, function(edge) {
                var new_edge = $("<li>");
                new_edge.text("Neighbor: " + edges[edge].dest + ", Token: " + edges[edge].token);
                $("#uncuratedGraphsModalBody").append(new_edge);
            });
          });
          $("#" + occurence + "thresholdSlider").on('input', function(thresh) {
            threshold($("#" + occurence + "thresholdSlider").val());
          });
          //adjust threshold
          function threshold(thresh) {
              var edge_by_person = edge_by_person_per_threshold_unweighted[occurence + "edge_by_person_unweighted"];
              graph.links.splice(0, graph.links.length);
              for (var i = 0; i < graphRec.links.length; i++) {
                var source = graphRec.links[i].source.name;
                var dest = graphRec.links[i].target.name;
                var value = -1;
                var edges = edge_by_person[source];
                var found = false;
                for (var edge = 0; !found && edge < edges.length; edge++) {
                  if (dest == edges[edge].dest) {
                    value = edges[edge].token;
                    found = true;
                  }
                }
                if (value >= thresh) {
                  graph.links.push({
                    source: graphRec.links[i].source.name,
                    target: graphRec.links[i].target.name,
                    value: graphRec.links[i].value
                  });
                }
              }
              restart();
          }
          //Restart the visualisation after any node and link changes
          function restart() {
            link = link.data(graph.links);
            link.exit().remove();
            link.enter().insert("line", ".node").attr("class", "link")
            .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

            node = node.data(graph.nodes);
            node.enter().insert("circle", ".cursor").attr("class", "node")
              .attr("r", 5)
              .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
              .call(force.drag);
            force
              .nodes(node)
              .links(link)
              .start();
          }
        });
      }
```

This is the JS that he added from the JsFiddle I linked:

[image: JsAddition]

This is my understanding: If you have the same nodes, and you just remove a few edges from graph.links, can't you just do a force.start()? When I directly copy his restart() function, all links are broken, and none get redrawn, even though doing a console.log(graph.links) shows the correct links to-redraw.

I believe that it's talking to the wrong nodes at this point, maybe the wrong SVG. I have multiple SVGs on the same page.