# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'weight' of undefined D3.JS

Tags: python, d3.js, graph, graphics, force-layout

I am trying to display a graph using D3.JS and I am getting this error.

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357974/d3-js-cannot-read-property-weight-of-undefined-when-manually-defining-both) & [this](https://github.com/christophergandrud/d3Network/issues/18) both nothing worked out.

before sending my data to D3.JS I have verified and here is my nodes and edges

> 0
>
> {group: 4, id: 0, name: "LATS1"} 1
>
> {group: 1, id: 455, name: "ROCK2"} 2
>
> {group: 1, id: 456, name: "MK13"} 3
>
> {group: 1, id: 457, name: "PDPK1"} 4
>
> {group: 1, id: 458, name: "AAPK1"} 5
>
> {group: 1, id: 459, name: "STK3"} 6
>
> {group: 1, id: 460, name: "NEK11"} 7
>
> {group: 1, id: 461, name: "LATS1"} 8
>
> {group: 1, id: 462, name: "CDK1"} 9
>
> {group: 1, id: 463, name: "DYRK2"} 10
>
> {group: 1, id: 464, name: "NUAK1"} 11
>
> {group: 2, id: 1, name: "MSX2"} 12
>
> {group: 2, id: 2, name: "G6PD"} 13
>
> {group: 2, id: 3, name: "ALDH2"} 14
>
> {group: 2, id: 4, name: "CDN2A"} 15
>
> {group: 2, id: 5, name: "TITIN"} 16
>
> {group: 2, id: 6, name: "SP1"} 17
>
> {group: 2, id: 7, name: "RAD"} 18
>
> {group: 2, id: 8, name: "SMAD3"} 19
>
> {group: 2, id: 9, name: "APC1"} 20
>
> {group: 2, id: 10, name: "TY3H"}
>
> length : 21

And here are my edges

> {label: 0.785, source: 0, target: 1} 1
>
> {label: 0.787, source: 0, target: 2} 2
>
> {label: 0.778, source: 0, target: 3} 3
>
> {label: 0.777, source: 0, target: 4} 4
>
> {label: 0.774, source: 0, target: 5} 5
>
> {label: 0.786, source: 0, target: 6} 6
>
> {label: 0.776, source: 0, target: 7} 7
>
> {label: 0.769, source: 0, target: 8} 8
>
> {label: 0.763, source: 0, target: 9} 9
>
> {label: 0.762, source: 0, target: 10} 10
>
> {label: 0.825, source: 455, target: 0} 11
>
> {label: 0.792, source: 456, target: 0} 12
>
> {label: 0.811, source: 457, target: 0} 13
>
> {label: 0.748, source: 458, target: 0} 14
>
> {label: 0.747, source: 459, target: 0} 15
>
> {label: 0.744, source: 460, target: 0} 16
>
> {label: 0.751, source: 461, target: 0} 17
>
> {label: 0.754, source: 462, target: 0} 18
>
> {label: 0.752, source: 463, target: 0} 19
>
> {label: 0.73, source: 464, target: 0} length
>
> 20

You can verify there are no missing references in links. All nodes are available.

But when I send these nodes and edges to D3.JS, it assigns weight:0 to some nodes which causes some link-sources as undefined and returns this error.

If I display my nodes and links after sending them to Force D3.JS, they are like this

Nodes:

> {group: 4, id: 0, name: "LATS1", index: 0, weight: 10} 1
>
> {group: 1, id: 455, name: "ROCK2", index: 1, weight: 1} 2
>
> {group: 1, id: 456, name: "MK13", index: 2, weight: 1} 3
>
> {group: 1, id: 457, name: "PDPK1", index: 3, weight: 1} 4
>
> {group: 1, id: 458, name: "AAPK1", index: 4, weight: 1} 5
>
> {group: 1, id: 459, name: "STK3", index: 5, weight: 1} 6
>
> {group: 1, id: 460, name: "NEK11", index: 6, weight: 1} 7
>
> {group: 1, id: 461, name: "LATS1", index: 7, weight: 1} 8
>
> {group: 1, id: 462, name: "CDK1", index: 8, weight: 1} 9
>
> {group: 1, id: 463, name: "DYRK2", index: 9, weight: 1} 10
>
> {group: 1, id: 464, name: "NUAK1", index: 10, weight: 1} 11
>
> {group: 2, id: 1, name: "MSX2", index: 11, weight: 0} 12
>
> {group: 2, id: 2, name: "G6PD", index: 12, weight: 0} 13
>
> {group: 2, id: 3, name: "ALDH2", index: 13, weight: 0} 14
>
> {group: 2, id: 4, name: "CDN2A", index: 14, weight: 0} 15
>
> {group: 2, id: 5, name: "TITIN", index: 15, weight: 0} 16
>
> {group: 2, id: 6, name: "SP1", index: 16, weight: 0} 17
>
> {group: 2, id: 7, name: "RAD", index: 17, weight: 0} 18
>
> {group: 2, id: 8, name: "SMAD3", index: 18, weight: 0} 19
>
> {group: 2, id: 9, name: "APC1", index: 19, weight: 0} 20
>
> {group: 2, id: 10, name: "TY3H", index: 20, weight: 0}

Edges

> {label: 0.785, source: {…}, target: {…}} 1
>
> {label: 0.787, source: {…}, target: {…}} 2
>
> {label: 0.778, source: {…}, target: {…}} 3
>
> {label: 0.777, source: {…}, target: {…}} 4
>
> {label: 0.774, source: {…}, target: {…}} 5
>
> {label: 0.786, source: {…}, target: {…}} 6
>
> {label: 0.776, source: {…}, target: {…}} 7
>
> {label: 0.769, source: {…}, target: {…}} 8
>
> {label: 0.763, source: {…}, target: {…}} 9
>
> {label: 0.762, source: {…}, target: {…}} 10
>
> {**label: 0.825, source: undefined, target: {…}}** 11
>
> {label: 0.792, source: 456, target: 0} 12
>
> {label: 0.811, source: 457, target: 0} 13
>
> {label: 0.748, source: 458, target: 0} 14
>
> {label: 0.747, source: 459, target: 0} 15
>
> {label: 0.744, source: 460, target: 0} 16
>
> {label: 0.751, source: 461, target: 0} 17
>
> {label: 0.754, source: 462, target: 0} 18
>
> {label: 0.752, source: 463, target: 0} 19
>
> {label: 0.73, source: 464, target: 0}

That bold line is causing this problem

Here is my code for force

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
        .nodes(nodes_, function(d) {
            if(d.weight == 0) {d.weight=1;}
            }
        )
        .links(edges_)
        .size([w, h])
        .linkDistance(function (d, i) {
            if (d['target']['group']==1){

            return linkDistance1;
            }
            if (d['target']['group']==2){

                return linkDistance2;
            }
        })
        .charge([-500])
        .theta(0.8)
        .gravity(0.05)
        .start();
```

Comment: You are using v3, in v3 link target and source numbers refer to the node's by their index/order in the node array (in v4/5 you can specify an index property such as `id`). Once you get to link with source 455 your node/link initialization will throw an error because your nodes array does not have 456 items in it.

Comment: Thanks. But node 456 is available in the nodes list. Its there

Comment: If you are sharing your complete dataset, you don't have 456 nodes in your dataset, the link isn't looking up the id, it is looking up node with index 455 in the nodes array

Comment: If you want to use v3 you can use a named node (as specified by `id` for example) by replacing the identifying number/string with the node directly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51390262/7106086